# Make Java App resilient

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, high-availability

We do have a distributed (note: not microservices) system which connects to one huge database (PostgresSQL - 9.3.13). We had in the last year different outages on this DB. The DB is kind of HA as well and the virtual IP floats correctly to the slave.

Our application is using Java, and as soon as the Master is not reachable anymore, our application starts to scream (via logs, which is fine) but unfortunately does not reconnect to the new master.

How can someone do this in a more resilient way? The best would be if the connection is kept active and the CP does connect to the new master as soon as it is available and (best case) all running updates/inserts are rolled back and started again on the new master.

For me the problem seems to be the Virtual IP and the connection pool plainly does not reconnect.

We do use DBCP2 as a connection pool. The data layer is hibernate.

Comment: Put something like pgbouncer or pgpool in front of the two servers they can make the fail over pretty much invisible for the client. Or use a more modern connection pool like the native Apache Tomcat Pool which handles re-connects better.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. We do use DBCP2, which should be pretty similar to Tomcats implementation. How production ready are pgbouncer and pgpool. Any experiences? We had a consultant in here, which claimed, that only the application is responsible to this resilience issue. And he said that both (pgbouncer and pgpool) are not really production ready. Me on the other hand (as an application developer) blames the HA stuff of the DB.